# Mixpanel track event when check box is checked

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I am using mixpanel JS for metrics, and I have to capture an event for the form when user tries to submit a form and there is check box which allows user to signup for newsletter . I want to track users who signup and check the box, and no idea as how to approach this problem. Thats how my form looks like

```
<form id="form_send_email" novalidate="novalidate"> 
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="learn_more" id="learn_more" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/>
<label for="learn_more" id="learn_more_label" class="css-label">Learn more about our products and sign up</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually one want to do some client side validation of forms before actually sending them to the server. There are loads of JS libs that can help you out, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for example.
Then if all data looks ok, send the track request to mixpanel and submit the form.

Mixpanel have client libs for [quite some languages](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference), you might want to send the the track request from your server?